# Having issue On Loading All JSON Data into Markers Layer With in For Loop

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have a code like below which is suppose to add over 600 points into a GraphicLayer `projectsG` and eventually add the `projectsG` to `layer1` and `map` but I am not sure what I am doing wrong in

```
projectsG = new esri.Graphic(project, symbol).setInfoTemplate(projectInfoTemplate);
}
console.log(thepoints);
layer1 = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
for (i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
    layer1.add(projectsG);
}
```

part which only adds the **last** project into the map! Can you please take a look at following code and let me know what I  am doing wrong in looping?

```
  var layer1, 
  var thepoints=[];
  var projectInfoTemplate;
  var projectsG;

var points = [
   {
      "ProjectID":"15260",
      "Longitude":"-118.641508",
      "Latitude":"51.949915",
   },
   {
      "ProjectID":"17043",
      "Longitude":"-125.444557",
      "Latitude":"51.097552",
   },
   ....
      {
      "ProjectID":"13009",
      "Longitude":"-130.257086",
      "Latitude":"56.882834",
   },
   {
      "ProjectID":"17088",
      "Longitude":"-124.160699",
      "Latitude":"50.897618",
   }
];

function drawSeries1() {
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var projects = points[i];
    var project = new esri.geometry.Point(projects.Longitude, projects.Latitude);                  
    project = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(project);

    var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("e-Chartreuse.png", 32, 32);
    projectInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate(); 
    projectInfoTemplate.setTitle("Project Details");
    projectInfoTemplate.setContent('<div>Some Att Here</div> ');

    projectsG = new esri.Graphic(project, symbol).setInfoTemplate(projectInfoTemplate);
    thepoints.push(projectsG);
}
console.log(thepoints);
layer1 = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
for (i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
    layer1.add(projectsG);
}
map.addLayer(layer1);           


}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for loop :

```
for (var i = 0; i < thepoints.length; ++i) {
  layer1.add(thepoints[i]);
}
```

even "better", you could skip that last for loop, and replace `thepoints.push(projectsG);` with `layer1.add(projectsG);` in the previous for loop